# What is the significance of 'context' in various constructor of Intent class when starting an activity

Tags: android

I had come across a code snippet which calls for an activity without referring to any context. Before, i was considering that context is used to tell about the calling component. But as i came see that another component can be called without any reference to context, it makes me wonder what purpose it might be serving. please put some light on it.

Here is the code which calls for an activity without referring to 'context'

```
Intent i=new Intent();
ComponentName cn=new ComponentName("application package name","fully qualified class name");
i.setComponent(cn);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: The code in your snippet does not "call for an activity without referring to 'context'".

Comment: yes thats true, but i wanted to know about the purpose of context that is pass as an argument in various constructor of intent

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it sounds like the context is only used to retrieve the current package name. So if you set the package name yourself you don't have to pass the context.

(This may change in the future.)

Emmanuel

Comment: Yes, it do so.. conceptually context seem to play a role which gives information and functionality related to application, kind of application object